# Role error while configuring saml signing certificate for robin powered

Tags: azure-active-directory, saml, saml-2.0

> Error : Your role does not have the permissions required to manage signing certificates.

How to fix this?

Previously I was able to setup up signle signon for multiple applications but I didnt receive any error related signing certificate but robin powered is not allowing

Answer (score 0):

To configure certificate you should be a member of One of the following roles: Global Administrator, Cloud Application Administrator, Application Administrator, or owner of the service principal.

Comment: Previously I was able to setup up signle signon for multiple applications but I didnt receive any error related signing certificate but robin powered is not allowing